# sql statement to access sql

Tags: sql, ms-access

```
SELECT eventID,
       eventRedacteur,
       eventEvenement,
       eventGenreId,
       eventDatum,
       eventLocatieId,
       eventLocatieNaam,
       eventPlaatsId,
       eventBijzonderheden,
       eventBezoekers,
       lokId,
       lokNaam,
       lokUrl,
       pltsId,

       (SELECT pltsNaam
         FROM tblAgendaPlaatsen
         WHERE pltsId=tblAgendaPunten.eventPlaatsId) AS eventPlaatsNaam,

       (SELECT genreNaam
         FROM tblAgendaGenre
         WHERE genreId=tblAgendaPunten.eventGenreId) AS eventGenre,
       lokadres,
       lokhuisnr
FROM tblAgendaPunten
LEFT JOIN tblAgendaLocaties ON eventLocatieId=tblAgendaLocaties.lokId
```

I get a join not supported error.

I also tried to remake the SQL in Access, but no luck.

Anyone can help?

Comment: Are you sure the error is related specifically to this query? Could you update your post with the *exact* error message?

Comment: Try specifying the table name in the `ON` clause of your join: `ON tblAgendaPunten.eventLocatieId=tblAgendaLocaties.lokId`

Comment: Also, I don't think Access supports having multiple records in an expression containing a subquery. You'll probably need something like `(SELECT First(pltsNaam) FROM tblAgendaPlaatsen WHERE pltsId=tblAgendaPunten.eventPlaatsId) AS eventPlaatsNaam`

Comment: @ZevSpitz Your comment re table name is the answer, AFAIK, because it gives that exact error message.

Comment: @Remou Does Access support multiple records in an expression containing a subquery?

Comment: @ZevSpitz No, but I suspect that is not the problem, and if it is, then your query below will return multiple duplicate rows, which will probably not suit, yesno?

Comment: Right, but I assume that `tblAgendaPlaatsen` and `tblAgendaGenre` are lists of values, with their respective IDs being primary keys. In that case, getting the values in a subquery will not be allowed, even though in fact the subqueries are only returning one record per row.

Comment: @ZevSpitz So in the above, `WHERE pltsId=tblAgendaPunten.eventPlaatsId` will return one value only, which is valid. (As an aside, I am not notified of comments to this post).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably replace your subqueries with joins:

```
SELECT eventID,
   eventRedacteur,
   eventEvenement,
   eventGenreId,
   eventDatum,
   eventLocatieId,
   eventLocatieNaam,
   eventPlaatsId,
   eventBijzonderheden,
   eventBezoekers,
   lokId,
   lokNaam,
   lokUrl,
   pltsId,

   pltsNaam,

   genreNaam,

   lokadres,
   lokhuisnr
FROM ((tblAgendaPunten
LEFT JOIN tblAgendaLocaties 
    ON tblAgendaPunten.eventLocatieId = tblAgendaLocaties.lokId)
LEFT JOIN tblAgendaPlaatsen
    ON tblAgendaPunten.eventPlaatsId = tblAgendaPlaatsen.pltsId)
LEFT JOIN tblAgendaGenre
    ON tblAgendaPunten.eventGenreId = tblAgendaGenre.genreId
```

Note the parentheses around each nested join.

Comment: This should probably be in a comment on the original question, but I put it as an answer to show the formatted SQL.